# Multiple and on INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT Email 
FROM minisecurity.my_aspnet_membership m         
INNER JOIN minisecurity.my_aspnet_details t ON t.id = m.userId         
INNER JOIN minisecurity.my_aspnet_usersinroles r ON m.userId = r.userId and r.roleId = '7'         
WHERE t.customerid = '2'
```

On my second `INNER JOIN` I want to filter so that I get a result where roleId is either 6 or 7.

I tried both

```
INNER JOIN minisecurity.my_aspnet_usersinroles r
    ON m.userId = r.userId and r.roleId = '7' and r.roleId = '6'
```

and

```
INNER JOIN minisecurity.my_aspnet_usersinroles r 
    ON m.userId = r.userId and r.roleId = '7' or r.roleId = '6'
```

but both returns wrong result.

How is this done correctly?

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result out of those sample data.

Comment: What's the difference between a customer and a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND` has [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) over `OR`, so what you want is:

```
 INNER JOIN ... ON m.userId = r.userId and (r.roleId = '7' or r.roleId = '6')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below query-

```
SELECT Email 
FROM minisecurity.my_aspnet_membership m         
INNER JOIN minisecurity.my_aspnet_details t ON t.id = m.userId         
INNER JOIN minisecurity.my_aspnet_usersinroles r ON m.userId = r.userId       
WHERE t.customerid = 2 and r.roleId in (6,7);
```

you can also use OR but in is more optimized than OR-

```
SELECT Email 
FROM minisecurity.my_aspnet_membership m         
INNER JOIN minisecurity.my_aspnet_details t ON t.id = m.userId         
INNER JOIN minisecurity.my_aspnet_usersinroles r ON m.userId = r.userId       
WHERE t.customerid = 2 and (r.roleId=6 OR r.roleId=7);
```

Note: As you are using inner join, so you can use additional condition either with on clause or in where clause.

Thanks @strawberry for editing to make answer better.

@Andy: Strawberry removed '' after considering that these fields are integer type and not char/varchar type, but if any field is not integer then must use ''.

Comment: I doubt that IN is any more optimized than OR. However, comparing integers to integers IS more optimized than comparing strings to integers.

Comment: @Strawberry: right now I don't have any document to support it but my experience is that mysql uses index better with in clause than OR.

Comment: If field is not integer, make field integer.